# Basement Apartment Tile Flooring Question

Tags: concrete, basement, flooring, tile

I am just starting construction on an 800 sq ft basement apartment. Over the years I have had a number of basement water issues in various properties, and I'd like to avoid this if at all possible. I'd like the flooring to be something its tough for clients to wreck, or if there's a water leak. I'm considering doing ceramic or other stone tile, right on the 80yo concrete. Is there any issue with me tiling the entire empty basement, and then framing over it? It seems like it would be WAY easier, not going all around walls, in closets, through doorways etc. We can just tile drill holes to set framing.

Is there anything I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Tiles are quite fragile, they break easily.  Framing on top of them might lead to breaks where you do not want them.  The floor will need to be very close to be perfectly flat(not level, a flat slope is okay).  An 80 year old floor might not be.   A tiny ridge of concrete might be enough to break a tile by walking on it, tiles do not bend.  Replacing set tiles is a PITA.

Comment: I hear ya, and I'm on board with your idea, but I do have some questions that would effect my answer.  Does the floor have a floor drain?   are you concerned about water leaks above the floor or under it. (coming up through concrete) ?

Comment: I'm assuming your intent is to frame on top of the tiles only on interior walls.  For exterior walls, there's no reason not to frame directly on the concrete (well, you want sill gasket, of course).  How would you secure the bottom plates through the tile?

Comment: There are a couple of floor drains. I’m not concerned at all about ground water only about leaks inside the apartment. I’ve had to rip up carpet and vinyl too many times in the past 15 years for a water line leak, toilet overflow or water heater burst. So I was thinking if I tile it and then set the walls above the tile with a waterproof gasket of some sort I could avoid future issues. Tiling all around the walls would take me 2-3 times as long as just tiling the wide open basement and then framing. I do agree on the fragility so we would have to be careful drilling for the anchors.